# Postfixを使ってメール送信した際の、表示送信元(Gmail)を変更したい

Tags: postfix, mail

Ubuntu14.04を使っています。
同じサーバにPostfixのメールサーバにてmailコマンドを使ってメール送信します。

```
$ echo "Test Mail." | mail -s "test mail" -r from@test.jp to@gmail.com
```

上記のコマンドでメールはto@gmail.com宛に飛びますが、Gmailで見るとサーバにログインしているアカウントが送信元となって表示されます。例えば、loginAというログインユーザであれば、送信元の表示はloginAと表示されています。これをfromUserに変更したいです。
もちろんGmailでloginAをマウスでオーバーレイすると、from@test.jpというのは表示されます。

どのように送信元の表示が変更して送信できるのでしょうか？
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail コマンドは From ヘッダをつけないので、Postfix がメールを作成したOSのユーザーから From ヘッダを生成しているのだと思います。

mail コマンドで From ヘッダをつけるために、次のようにして実行してみればよいと思います。

```
echo "Test Mail." | mail -a "From: fromUser <from@test.jp>" -s "test mail" -r from@test.jp to@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

postfix がら **SMTP-Auth** で smtp.gmail.com 経由でメールを送信しているのでしょうか。

Gmail の「アカウントとインポート」設定で、「名前」(From のメールアドレス)に "from@test.jp" を追加すれば、"From: from@test.jp" ヘッダを付けたメールはそのまま削除されずに宛先まで届きます。

ただし、"Sender: loginA@gmail.com" ヘッダも付くので、送信者がどのように表示されるかはメールクライアントによります。